# How to create subquery with Laravel Eloquent Between two tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, rest, eloquent

hello everyone I am new in Laravel development and I am wondering how to create subquery between two tables, for example, I want to execute this query :

```
SELECT * FROM `contracts` 
WHERE `trainer_id` = '1' OR id IN (
    SELECT `contract_id` FROM `trainees` 
    WHERE `user_id` = '1'
)
```

I test it in and it works fine as I want, I want to know how to write it in Laravel eloquent

Comment: You may use Reletionship: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

Comment: post laravel code you tried. people here can help you find and correct the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your Model is named Contract you can use the following syntax to achieve what you want:

```
Contracts::where('trainer_id', '1')
    ->orWhere(function ($subquery) {
        $subquery->whereIn('id', function ($query) {
            $query->select('contract_id')
                ->from('trainees')
                ->where('user_id', '1');
        })
    })->get();
```